# Connect an eMMC card with SPI interface

Tags: microcontroller, spi

I am creating a PCB based on a concerto microcontroller.

I need an eMMC memory. Texas instruments provides me with a driver for an SD card , based on SPI interface. However, eMMC cards dont suppote SPI interface.

Is there any eMMC memory with SPI interface on the market? If not, then how can I interface an eMMC card with the concerto microcontroller using an SPI interface?

Answer (score 0):

As per the specification, SPI interface was removed from eMMC. So looks like you are not going to get any eMMC chip with SPI support. 
If you have some free GPIOs, then you can use those to simulate all the data lines and CMD line too. 
I would prefer you use the GPIOs. 
The same concept is used with I2C if you remember "Bit Banging".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any guide about how to write the software for the gpios for such a connection?

Comment: Not sure as I haven't done it. It was just a suggestion. You need to go through the EMMC spec and understand the whole initialization procedure. Then you need to understand how you are going to simulate clock by writing 1 and 0 in a particular speed, etc.